# Using styles to modify frame colour

Tags: python, tabs, frame, ttk

I am unable to modify a colour when using ttk to create tabbed frames. In a standart Tkinter frame, the process is simple. I am using Python 2.7.6
I'd appreciate a tip as to where I'm going wrong.

```
root = Tkinter.Tk()

s = ttk.Style()
s.configure('tab1', background='black', foreground='blue')

n = ttk.Notebook(root)

f1 = ttk.Frame(style='tab1.TFrame') # first tab
f2 = ttk.Frame() # second tab

n.add(f1, text='Log Ticket')
n.add(f2, text='Work orders')
n.grid()
```

As I understand the documentation, the TFrame default settings (Grey) should be updates with the style 'tab1' that I have applied to the frame creation, but nothing changes.

Answer (score 1):

This will works:

```
import Tkinter, ttk

root = Tkinter.Tk()

s = ttk.Style()
s.configure('tab1.TFrame', background='black', foreground='blue')

n = ttk.Notebook(root)


f1 = ttk.Frame(root,style='tab1.TFrame') # first tab
f2 = ttk.Frame() # second tab

n.add(f1, text='Log Ticket')
n.add(f2, text='Work orders')
n.pack(fill=Tkinter.BOTH, expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I was not wanting to use .pack, just grid, however you beat me by minutes. I obviously needed sleep. All I needed to change was the line:
s.configure('tab1.TFrame', background='black', foreground='blue') I had not grasped the syntax. Thanks very much for the follow up.